# Convert yyyymmdd string to mmm-yyyy format

Tags: impala

I have an input data which comes as a string *'yyyymmdd'* and i want to convert it to **mmm-yyyy** format.

Answer (score 0):

Please use this

```
select from_timestamp(to_timestamp('20211004' , 'yyyyMMdd'),'MMM-yyyy') as str
```

[image]